# Updating the progress dialog on an uploading process

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

My program is uploading a video from SD Card without a problem but I am trying to add a progress dialog to show how much bytes uploaded so far in percentage. I am using async task. However, altough I am able to show the dialog on the screen. The dialog is not updating. After the upload finished it turns to 100/100 and it dissappears. Could you please help me how can I update the progress dialog?

```
package com.isoft.uploader2;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class Proje2Activity extends Activity
 {
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button select =(Button)findViewById(R.id.select);
        Button back =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back1);
        Button camera =(Button)findViewById(R.id.camera);

        //Select a video from SD-Card
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                openGaleryVideo();
            }
        }); 

        //Turn back
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        }); 

        //Record a video
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }); 
    }
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public static final int SELECT_VIDEO=1;
public static final String TAG="UploadActivity";
String path="";

//Open Gallery
public void openGaleryVideo()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),SELECT_VIDEO);
}

//Select the video and start to execute the upload class
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) 
        {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            path= getPath(videoUri);
            upload upload = new upload();
            upload.execute();
        }
    }
}

//Getting the URİ from the SD Card
public String getPath(Uri uri)
{   
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

//ASYNC TASK Upload Class which uploads the file and shows the progress via a dialog
public class upload extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void> 
{
     //Initializations
     public ProgressDialog dialog;
     File file=new File(path);  
     String urlServer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     String filename=file.getName();
     int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize,progress;
     byte[] buffer;
     int maxBufferSize = 20*1024*1024;

    //Before start to upload the file creating a dialog
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() 
    {
         dialog = new ProgressDialog(Proje2Activity.this);
         dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
         dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         dialog.setTitle("UPLOADING");
         dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
         dialog.setProgress(0);
         dialog.setMax(100);
         dialog.show();
            //Burada işlemi yapmadan önce ilk olarak ne yaptırmak istiyorsak burada yaparız.
            //Örneğin burada dialog gösterip "onPostExecute()" metodunda dismiss edebiliriz.
    }

    //Uploading the file in background with showing the progress
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) file.length());

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",  "multipart/form-data");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SD-FileName", filename);//This will be the file name
        final DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {   
            progress=0;
            progress+=bytesRead;
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 
            publishProgress((int)((progress*100)/(file.length())));
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            progress+=bytesRead;
        }//end of while statement
        fileInputStream.close();
        publishProgress(100); 
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        }//end of try body

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error: ", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
     }//end of doInBackground method

     //making an update on progress
     @Override
     public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        }//end of onProgressUpdate

     //After finishing the progress the dialog will disappear!
     @Override
     public void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            try 
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } //End of the second try body
            catch(Exception e) 
            {

            }
        }//end of onPostExecute method
}// end of asyncTask class 
}//end of main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problems i noticed are :

- your `bufferSize` can be total file length. so, in one read itself, the buffer can be full. i changed it to 512 to get noticeable change in progressbar
- your resets `progress` variable inside the loop
- also, you are writing the entire buffer (ie from `0` to `bufferSize`) to the output stream. not the actual `bytesRead. at the last portions you may get error values.
- before reading again, you are not restting the `buffer`

updated code

```
bufferSize = 512;
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
progress=0;

while (bytesRead > 0)
{   

    progress+=bytesRead;
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 
    publishProgress((int)((progress*100)/(file.length())));
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}//end of while statement
fileInputStream.close();
publishProgress(100); 
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should look something like this, there was a couple of logical errors in your code.

```
// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
progress=0;
progress+=bytesRead;

while (bytesRead > 0)
{   
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 
    publishProgress((int)((progress/file.length())*100));
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    progress+=bytesRead;
}//end of while statement
```

**Update:** I just noticed, that you use a buffer with 20MB, change `maxBufferSize` to `int maxBufferSize = 1024`, and it should work.

Comment: I tried but the problem is still same there is no progress on dialog

Comment: I updated my answer. **First** you added `bytesRead` to `progress` two times in the loop. **Second** you set progress to 0 in every iteration of your loop. **Third** your math to compute the percentage was wrong.