# Thread runs after statements below are executed

Tags: android, database, realm

I am showing a countdown while Realm  **dataBase** is loaded from the **asset** file

```
 SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
            if (isFirstRun)
            {
                handler = new Handler();
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(context,FirstRun.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                };
                handler.post(r);


                RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                        .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                        .migration(new in.webic.longevity.longevity.Word())
                        .assetFile(context, "Default.realm")
                        .schemaVersion(0)
                        .build();

                realm = realm.getInstance(config);
                realm.close();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
                editor.commit();

            }
```

**Problem:**

> countdown should be show, rather a blank screen while asset file is
>   copying as default database

Yet activity starts after few seconds(which is in the thread) taken by the code below to load the asset file,
Is there a better way to show countdown while Realm configuration is setup.
any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: so whats your problem? I didn't get it exactly!

Comment: You tried to call this code in `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` Activity?

Comment: yes @DouglasJunior its in the mainActivity onCreate method

Comment: @LalitPoptani edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a countdown, you must to copy the file manually.

- How to copy file from assets to internal storage: [Android - Copy assets to internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218775/android-copy-assets-to-internal-storage)
- How to update a progress or countdown: [Updating the progress dialog on an uploading process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340735/updating-the-progress-dialog-on-an-uploading-process)
- How to copy in correct Realm path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36324183/2826279

And then, run the slow code in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Like this:

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(...) {
        // init view

        new SlowTask().execute();
     }


     class SlowTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

              // realm slow code here
              return null;
          }

          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
             // start your next activity here
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: sorry sir my whole application depends on database which needs to be loaded first hence, code needs to be run synchronously only

Comment: Yes, my sample must be called in launcher activity, before everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't estimate the processing time. So countdown would not be a good option. Show some progress dialog before loading data from assets, then after data is loaded, dismiss the dialog.

**Update:**
Actually what your problem is your thread executes before data is loaded! fine?. 
What you need to do is to do all processing task in AsyncTask class in which you should show progress dialog in `onPreExecute(...)` method. then do processing work in `doInBackground(...)` method. then in  `onPostExecute(...)`, dismiss progress dialog.

Comment: i agree, but my question run a thread before the below statement i.e default configuration is loaded

Answer (score 0):

1. If you run some time-consuming task in main thread ("UI-thread", thread executed your Activity lifecycle methods) of your application, your app UI will be "freezed", which is generally undesirable. All background tasks (file\network io, heavy calculations) should be executed in separate thread. 
   If the background operation is started only for showing something in UI, consider using [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)
2. If you need your object to be accessible from several Activites\Fragments, consider extending [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and place link to your object there. If you need to "initialize" your object (load db in your case) at every app start, this can be done in onCreate() method of your Application class. If some objects (Activities) need to know, when the initialization is finished, you can use **Observer** pattern. 
   Sample code:
   Your Application class:

   ```
   public void onCreate() {   
       super.onCreate(); 
       mHandler = new Handler(); //for communicating with UI thread
       if (firstRun) { 
           new Thread(new Runnable() { 
               loadMyDb(); 
               mHandler.post(new Runnable()) { 
                   notifyListeners(); 
               } 
           } 
       } 
   }
   ```

Your Activity class:

```
protected void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); 
    //setup your layout and views
    MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
    if (app.isDbLoaded()) {
        showContent();
    } else {
        showProgressBar();
        app.addDbLoadListener(this);
    }
 }

 public void onDbLoaded() {
     hideProgressBar();
     app.removeDbLoadListener(this);
     showContent();
 }
```

Comment: whole application depends on database which needs to be loaded first hence, code needs to be run synchronously only. so i am starting a new activity to show something and first activity will load the heavy task